Has Marvel shown Thor's hammer, Mjolnir, breaking through Invisible Woman's force fields?
In the Secret Wars #4 (2015) comic book, there's a scene where Doctor Doom and Susan von Doom (née Storm), aka the Invisible Woman, are observing a battle. Doom's Thor Corps—a group of Thor variants, each wielding their own Mjolnir—are fighting against the Cabal, led by the Maker (the Reed Richards from the Ultimate Marvel Universe).
During this scene, Susan comments on The Maker's force fields, noting that:

Even my force fields could not withstand the repeated hammering of a Mjolnir.

This implies that The Maker's force fields are impressively durable, easily shrugging off blows from multiple Mjolnirs.

Susan's statement got me wondering: Is this a reference to a prior event(s) where her own force fields were actually tested against Mjolnir? If so, in which comic book(s) did this occur?

She can pick Mjolnir up and move it around ; https://screenrant.com/fantastic-four-invisible-woman-thor-hammer-mjolnir/

I've no idea if Sue's statement there was a reference to one or more specific issues, but Thor did hammer through one of her force fields with repeated blows, while being mind-controlled by the Puppet Master in Marvel Two-In-One Vol. 1 #9.

The deed is almost done. Susan Richards lies unconscious--her force field shattered by the power of Thor's hammer--the hammer that even now raises to deliver the death blow.

Marvel Two-In-One Vol. 1 #9 (May, 1975)

